# Add MGRS custom Coordinate Reference System to QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj, mgrs

I am looking for a way to add MGRS custom Coordinate Reference System to QGIS.

How do I get the Proj.4 cartographic parameters for Military Grid Reference System (MGRS) to add via Settings >> Custom CRS?

[image]

Comment: See the answer here:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261127/mgrs-grid-in-qgis/261144#261144  - MGRS isn't a single projected CRS, but has as many forms as the number of UTM zones.  MGRS is exactly the same as UTM zones, with EPSGs 326XX and 327XX (last two numbers the same as an MGRS grid prefix).  The only difference is that MGRS assigns letters to simplify the coded Easting and Northing numbers