# MGRS Grid Lines?

Tags: qgis-3, mgrs

I am very new to this. My current version of QGIS is 3.4.2-Madeira. I am trying to make a 7,500 scale map displaying MGRS gridlines.

> The Military Grid Reference System (MGRS) is the geocoordinate standard used by NATO militaries for locating points on Earth. The MGRS is derived from the Universal Transverse Mercator (UTM) grid system and the Universal Polar Stereographic (UPS) grid system, but uses a different labeling convention. ([source: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_Grid_Reference_System))

I have ESRI World Topo map as the base layer and Render is set to EPSG: 4326. I'm not sure if the Lat/Long Tools Plugin will have the function to display gridlines.

I saw a video where the coordinates were formatted using an expression: Left(Right(grid_number, 5), 2). I've tried and I am seeing "mb". Another time it just was not displaying the correct number. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Update: expression used was "Left(Right(@grid_number, 5), 2)"

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261127/mgrs-grid-in-qgis

Comment: That expression will output the left 2 characters of the right 5 characters of a text string in the field called "grid_number". So the output depends on what values you have in your "grid_number" field. What do the values in your "grid_number" field look like?