# Import MGRS vector (old projection) to QGIS

Tags: mgrs

I have large Excel tables of MGRS coordinates. These data were recorded from grid references based on maps  created in India 1960 projection. Is there any way to import these into QGIS to a) visualise without needing to convert to some X, Y / lat / long systems and b) reproject to WGS84?

Bear in mind that MGRS is self contained within just one field (ie, not the typical double X, Y fields)

Comment: check this https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/261144/49538

Comment: Thanks for that yes I saw that already. Unfortunately I don't need to generate a grid, i need to import an attribute table with MGRS coordinate format without converting it to X, Y if possible. Surely there must be a batch importer plugin for MGRS?